# Best way to use Stripe/Plaid link with android app?

Tags: android, stripe-payments, plaid

I'm trying to do ACH transactions with my android app and was wondering what the best way to integrate the Stripe and Plaid Link API's is, particularly in terms of the server-side handlers. I'm using firebase for my other backend needs, could I use it for this purpose too? Or would i need to use Node.js or something. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You'll definitely need to have server-side code, though you can probably use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) for that.

That said, it doesn't look like there's a [Plaid Link Android SDK](https://github.com/plaid/link) so you may have to send your Android users to a web UI for adding their ACH details.